# ASP.Net MVC Web page - hiding buttons based on Active Directory role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I am trying to figure out how to hide or show buttons and other items on a Razor/MVC web page.

I know I can "protect" actions with the Authorize attribute but I would like to show or hide certain buttons on a web page based on the Active Directory role/group that a user is in.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    if (User.IsInRole("Domain\\Group"))
    {
        <li >
     @Html.ActionLink("Only Admin", "ActionOnlyAdmin", "Admin", routeValues: new { @id =  id })
        </li>
    }
```

and controller

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Domain\\Group")]
    public ActionResult ActionOnlyAdmin(){}
```

Comment: My AD memberOf for the user I'm testing with looks like: CN=Admin,CN=Users,DC=Mydomain,DC=LOCAL 
Just using your example above I always get false.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to add a method to the model, something like CanUserAccess().

Then in the View I do like:

```
@if (Model.CanUserAccess(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('|')[0].ToString()))
{
  // display buttons or partial view containing buttons
}
```

Then in the model you can do whatever you need to do to return true or false in CanUserAccess.